# How to make pagination sit at the bottom of the page inside the tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination

I have page with tabs. Each tab has their own pagination. But I have problem in putting the pagination at the bottom of the tab. The current pagination that I have right now is sit above. I want to change it and put the pagination at the bottom of the tab page. How do change it in order to achieve the output that I want ?

this is my current pagination
[image]

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="category_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="category_1-tab">
  <br>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <br>
      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination" id="page_1"></ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

if(cat === 1 )
    {
        $("#category_1-tab").append(
            `
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <a onclick="getDetail('${e.id}')" class="accordion-head collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion-item-${index}">
                        <h6 class="title">${e.title}</h6>
                        <span class="accordion-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="accordion-item-${index}" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="accordion-inner" id="details_${e.kb_id}">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        );

    }

    $("#page_1").html(`${pagination}`);
```

How do I make the pagination sit at the bottom of the list inside the tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$("#category_1-tab").append( …` by `$("#category_1-tab").prepend( …`

[prepend](https://api.jquery.com/prepend) will insert your `div.accordion-item` before the `<br><div>` instead of adding at the end.